# HTML, CSS settings for showing the entire fb pop-up dialog

Tags: html, css

This problem is bugging me for days, and can't find a way to solve it.
Therefore, I would really appreciate i someone could help me.
This is the problem:
When a user clicks facebook LIKE button, then the "post to facebook" dialog pops up.
The problem is the pop up is not displayed completely - only partially.
Please take a look at this link: http://kbk-siroki.herokuapp.com/blog/posts/konektori-u-engleskom-jeziku

Answer (score 0):

You need following changes in your CSS:

```
.main {width: 100%}
.container_12{width: 100%}
.footer_bg { width: 100%; left:0; margin-left: 0px;}
```

Comment: Ankit, thanks for your reply. Your solution fixed that pop up is showing completely, and I like it. The problem is that now my footer gets messed up. Please take a look at the same link. Also  when I click LIKE button, inside the pop up text "KATEGORIJE" is displayed from the other element. Is it possible to make when a pop up shows up it goes over KATEGORIJE?

Comment: Also, "Lajkajte nas na facebooku" just above footer gets changed

Comment: The footer looks good to me. Can u provide image of what is the issue you are still facing.

Comment: Ankit, this is the footer screenshot: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/yyfyt ; this is where KATEGORIJE text shows up when I clck on like btn: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/sblzr ; this is "general" LIKE btn moved from previous position: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/mg7hm

Comment: Ankit, I managed to correct two from three items I mentioned above. The third item is: I would like to remove "KATEGORIJE" text that displays inside fb pop up when a user clicks the LIKE button. Can you help me with this please?